# Tuple of pointers to functions returning reference to variadic types

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++14, stdtuple

Don't let the question title scare you off! I believe this is simply a question of syntax.

I have this class

```
template<typename ... Types>
class test_class{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        T &get(){return std::get<T>(m_values);}

        template<typename T>
        void set(T &&t){std::get<T>(m_values) = t;}

        // scary part
        std::pair<std::tuple</* trouble */ Types&(*)()...>, std::tuple<void(*)(Types)...>> &getters_setters(){
            static std::pair<std::tuple<Types&&(*)()...>, std::tuple<void(*)(Types)...>> ret{
                std::make_tuple(get<Types>...),
                std::make_tuple(set<Types>...)
            };
            return ret;
        }

    private:
        std::tuple<Types...> m_values;
};
```

And would love to know the correct syntax for an expansion of the template parameter pack so that I can get a tuple of `T &get()` function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ellipses are in the right place, you just need to make sure that the types actually match.

1. Your getters and setters are member functions, so you need to use a pointer to member function type: `Types&(test_class::*)()...`; `&test_class::get<Types>...`
2. `set` takes an rvalue reference: `void(test_class::*)(Types&&)...`

Resulting code; compiles fine with gcc 4.9.1:

```
    std::pair<std::tuple<Types&(test_class::*)()...>,
            std::tuple<void(test_class::*)(Types&&)...>>&
    getters_setters()
    {
        static std::pair<std::tuple<Types&(test_class::*)()...>,
                std::tuple<void(test_class::*)(Types&&)...>> ret{
            std::make_tuple(&test_class::get<Types>...),
            std::make_tuple(&test_class::set<Types>...)
        };
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, the rvalue reference part was a typo

Comment: Try creating an instance of the class and calling the method; it fails for me :/

Comment: Hmm, must be something wrong with my code still. I'll just copy paste the code off your link, easier than trying to find the error.